# Slide de imagens de background

Tags: jquery, background, slide

Eu quero fazer um slide fadeIn/fadeOut com imagens de background. Eu tenho este codigo que parece estar a funcionar exepto a imagem de background não mudar. Alguma dica?

CSS:

```
body, html {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

jQuery:

```
$('body').css({
        "background-image":"url(imgs/imgTest.jpg)"
    });
    var imgsArray = ['imgs/imgTest.jpg', 'imgs/yo.jpg', 'imgs/hey.jpg'];

    setInterval(function(){
        for (var i = 0; i < imgsArray.length; i++) {
            $('body').css({
                "background-image": imgsArray[i]
            });
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Com o código abaixo você conseguirá regularmente

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').attr('style', 'background:url(http://www.lorempixel.com/300/300) no-repeat');

});
var imgsArray = ['http://www.lorempixel.com/300/300', 'http://www.lorempixel.com/300/300'];

setInterval(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < imgsArray.length; i++) {
        $('body').attr('style', 'background: url(' + imgsArray[i] + ') no-repeat');
    }
}, 1000);
```

No caso do exemplo, como estou pegando lorempixel do mesmo tamanho, ele atualiza tão rápido que pega a mesma imagem. Para funcionar, apenas altere o lorempixel para o caminho de sua imagem e além disso, ajuste a velocidade do seu `setInterval`.